# retrieve first date less than given date not working Excel

Tags: excel

i nees to retrieve first date less than a given date, this formula is working when the condition es greater than but not when condition in less than

```
INDEX($F$3:$F$7,MATCH(TRUE,B3>$F$3:$F$7,0))
```

**Retrieve first date greater than row dates works perfectly**

[image]

**Retrieve first date less than row dates (not working correctly)**

[image]

Comment: please put the formula as plain text and translate it into english.

Comment: ^^^ `INDICE` = `INDEX`; `COINCIDIR`=`MATCH`; `VERDADERO`=`TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because MATCH will return the first that matches that description which is always `04/01/2021`

With Office 365 we can use FILTER.

For the greater than:

```
=@SORT(FILTER($F$3:$F$7,B3<$F$3:$F$7),1,1)
```

for the less than:

```
=@SORT(FILTER($F$3:$F$7,B3>$F$3:$F$7),1,-1)
```

[image]

---

for older versions, keep the formula that works for greater than, but for less than we need to use AGGREGATE and not MATCH.

```
=INDEX($F$3:$F$7,AGGREGATE(14,7,(ROW($F$3:$F$7)-MIN(ROW($F$3:$F$7))+1)/($F$3:$F$7<B3),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, i am wondering there is a simpler way to do this with older Excel version (2010)